# Django objects error in view, why I got this error? It looks like my model does not exist

Tags: python, django

**This is my view code:**

```
class Planificare_concedii(AllView):
    template_name = "pep/planificare_concedii.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        magazinu = self.request.GET.get('magazinul')
        queryset = Planificare_concedii.objects.filter(magazin=magazinu)
        context = context = super(Planificare_concedii, self).get_context_data(
            *args, **kwargs)

        return context
```

**This is the error that I got in view page:**

```
AttributeError at /planificare_concedii/
type object 'Planificare_concedii' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: views don't have an objects attribute, models do.

Comment: Planificare_concedii is a view, not a model

Comment: It is not a model, it is a view. Please do *not* name your views the same as your models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, that solved my issue! have a nice day